# Does Canada accept the EU covid certificate as a proof of vaccination?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, covid-19, vaccinations

For entering Canada by air you need to show proof of Covid vaccination in print, and also upload it to the ArriveCAN app. The requirements for that proof are delightfully vague: "a photo or PDF file of the record of each dose of your vaccination, such as receipts, cards, or confirmations" ([source](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/covid-vaccinated-travellers-entering-canada))

The EU DCC is explicitly described as a vaccination proof for inter-EU travel only - the digital version only contains the QR code, while the paper version contains more details. But because the Canadian standards are so vague, the paper version might be enough actually. So my question is: has anyone tried entering Canada with the EU DCC vaccine record as their "proof of vaccination"?

The EU DCC seems to be the only vaccine proof that the Dutch authorities is willing to give out, except for the stamp in the [International Certificate of Vaccination booklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis).

Comment: In my opinion, it could theoretically work out if you have either a single dose covid vaccine or both certificates at hand, namely the first one after your first dose and the second one after your second dose. On my EU DCC, the single info I see about the first dose (and it is not explicit) is '2/2' meaning that I got two of them, while the source you referred to states that you should provide the record of each dose of your vaccination, with 'of each dose' highlighted in bold.

Comment: I don't know. Part of the reason for the delightful vagueness is that Canadian vaccination confirmation is given in a variety of forms. I was vaccinated in Canada and have one receipt from a pharmacy and one receipt from a vaccination clinic. I suspect that anything that looks official and has enough text on it that the border agent can see what vaccines you got, and when, would be sufficient (but I don't blame you for wanting more information).

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for your insight. If I can be sure that I'll be convincing a human border agent rather than a computer system, then what I should perhaps do is just gather as much documentation on my shots as possible - which together do have all the vaccine data one could wish for, it's just that each of those documents individually would probably not suffice.

Comment: I don't know what kind of review of the documents is done prior to arrival. I came across a land border from the US and only finished my ArriveCAN application < 1 hour before arrival (long story); got an automatic confirmation by e-mail almost immediately. When I got to the border the agent looked at the application on their computer system and said everything was OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to generate a PDF version of an EU Digital COVID Vaccination Certificate?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166417/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-pdf-version-of-an-eu-digital-covid-vaccination-cert)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk No, that question asks for file management whereas I'm asking whether such a certificate would even be approved. In any case, having just successfully passed the border, I will answer my own question with my findings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

Having made the trip I can report on my experiences. I was asked for my ArriveCAN and PCR test result on several locations including the departing airport check-in counter and various checks before and after boarding, but I was asked once for the proof of vaccination, at a special transit Corona check site on Toronto airport. The attendant accepted my International Certificate of Vaccination booklet, even though she said she had never seen such a thing before - but she saw my EU DCC too and told me that by far most travelers use that as a proof of vaccination. From what I gather, the print version is accepted as a valid proof of Covid-19 vaccination.

Of course your mileage may vary, as may Canada's entry rules, but if EU DCC is your only available vaccination receipt then I believe you still have a good chance of being let into Canada.

Note that I ended up having my connecting flight cancelled due to bad weather. That's travel!

**Addendum**

Partially relevant to the original question and good to know: after spending a couple weeks in Canada, I have found that every establishment I've come across that asked for a proof of vaccination (food courts, cinemas) recognise the EUDCC and accept it as a proof combined with a photo ID.

Comment: I shouldn't place this here, but, did you give them a quarantaine plan? How does that work?

Comment: @JorenVandamme you enter a theoretical quarantine address in the ArriveCAN app, that you can reach on your first day. I just picked my first hotel - I only booked it for a few days but I could theoretically extend it to 14 days. That's all the requirements met. The attendant at the Toronto airport just made me confirm the story verbally, she asked where I would be staying and I mentioned the hotel. That was the end of it.